# How to enable button when input field is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a requirement in which there is a form and if all the fields are filled then only submit button will be enabled else the submit button will be in disabled state.

[**This fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/M6BzW/576/) works fine for 1 input field:

```html
<button data-bind="enable: my">My Button</button>
<input type="text" name="hi" data-bind="value:my" />
```

```js
ko.applyBindings({ my: ko.observable() });
```

However, I don't know how to do this for *multiple* input fields like as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6BzW/577/). If there are some 10 input fields then how to enable the submit button if and only if all the fields are filled up.

Comment: Validation: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

Comment: @Anders Thanks for the useful link but I am already using parsley.js for form validation

Comment: @KyleMit Thanks for making my post look better

Comment: OK, havent worked with it. Hook up the button to its valid state then

Comment: @Anders I am new to this javascript frameworks.If you have worked with knockout.js then please post the answer.I will surely upvote

Comment: I havent wroekd with parsley.js. You need to make the VM aware of the valid state of the form. Use that to update the button. KO Validation si doing this for you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50785/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-anders)

Comment: @Anders you can give your answer in knockout

Comment: Since you're already using parsley.js (you should have mentioned this in the original question), you might want to look in to the knockout-parsley project which integrates the two: https://github.com/gdandar/Knockout-Parsley

Comment: @PatrickSteele thanks for the link.But it would be a better help if you provide as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<button data-bind="enable: isFormValid">My Button</button>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: text1, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: text2, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: text3, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: text4, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
```

**JS**:

```js
var vm = {
    text1: ko.observable(""),
    text2: ko.observable(""),
    text3: ko.observable(""),
    text4: ko.observable("")
}

vm.isFormValid = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.text1() && this.text2() && this.text3() && this.text4();
}, vm);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

See updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oliverw/s2VmL/1/). The key to solving viewmodel inter-property dependencies is [Knockout's computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).

Comment: your fiddle and my fiddle in the question works same http://jsfiddle.net/M6BzW/577/. When you fill one textfield then that value reflects in all the fields

Comment: Sorry actually I was looking at your answer and understanding the codes.So accepted your answer late.Sorry again.+1 for best answer

Comment: @JqueryLearner I did.

Comment: I tried with 2 fields as like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rKm9N/6/) but when I implement in my project then again its not working

Comment: @JqueryLearner Like I said. Strip down your problem to the very basics that demonstrate the problem and people might want to have a look at it. But most likely you will sort it out along the way which is much more valuable than having people spoon-feed you the solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50855/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-oliver-weichhold)

Answer (score 3):

You could use JQuery to solve this, by doing the following:

**HTML Markup:**

```
<button id="my" type="button" disabled="true">My Button</button>
<input id="hi" type="text" name="hi" />
```

**JQuery Script:**

```
if (allFields == valid) {
    $('#my').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

That should make your life a whole lot easier. Let me know if not.

Comment: The question was about Knockout.js

Comment: He has jquery as one of the tags, so I was basing my answer on that.

Comment: @StanCromlish Thanks for answering but I would prefer knockout.js and parsley.js first and I am not the downvoter

Comment: Thanks. @JqueryLearner. It's not a problem.  I understand the downvotes, even though my answer solves the problem.

Comment: Ill neutralize that down vote. Because I almost gave a Jquery solution myself. People are far to quick on down voting now days!

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I read the tags as well as the question.  But, I should've probably looked at the question more closely.

Comment: @StanCromlish its my fault not your fault.So why you should be punished for my fault.+1 for your jquery solution too