# Button not enabling when form fields are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a form and a submit button.When all the fields are filled then only the submit button will be enabled else it will be in disabled state.I am referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109010/how-to-enable-button-when-input-field-is-not-empty) but when I implemented that idea in my project then its not working.The button remain in disabled state all the even if all the fields are filled.I am not getting where exactly is the mistake happened.Please help.

This is my knockout code.

```
self.newPatient = ko.asyncCommand({

     execute: function(complete) {
         var vm = {
                 name: ko.observable(""),
                 password: ko.observable(""),
                    address: ko.observable(""),
                    username: ko.observable("")
                };

                vm.isFormValid = ko.computed(function() {
                    return this.name() && this.password() && this.address() && this.username();
                }, vm);

                ko.applyBindings(vm);
        var isValid=$('#addPatientForm').parsley( 'validate' );
        if(isValid){
        var patientJson=ko.toJSON(self.patient());
        formdata.append("json",patientJson);
        //self.enableButton(false);
     var imagepath= $.ajax({
                url: projectUrl+"newPatient", 
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (res) {
                    formdata = new FormData();
                    imagepath=res;
                    var length=self.patients().length;
                    var patient=self.patient();
                //  self.enableButton(true);
                }
     });    
     $('.alert-patient-success').show();        
     self.patients.removeAll();
    self.getPatients();
    /* $.when(self.patients.push(self.patient()),self.patient(new Patient()),self.dirtyFlag1().reset(),$('#patientTabs a:last').tab('show'))
         .always(complete);*/
     } 
     },
     canExecute: function(isExecuting) {
         return !isExecuting && isDirty() && isValid();
     }
 });
```

This is the save button code.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"data-bind="command: $root.newPatient, activity: $root.newPatient.isExecuting,enable: $root.newPatient.isFormValid" >
                                                    <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Save
                                                </button>
```

This is form

```
<form id="addPatientForm"  data-validate="parsley">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Name :</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend" >
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i></span>
                <input class="span8" type="text" data-bind="value: name,valueUpdate: 'keyup'" data-required="true" data-trigger="change" name="name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Address :</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i></span>
                <input class="span8" name="address" type="text" data-bind="value: address,valueUpdate: 'keyup'" data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Gender :</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i></span>
                <select class="span8" name="gender" data-bind="options: $root.genderOptions,value: gender,optionsCaption: 'Select Gender'" data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Consultant :</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="cus-user_suit"></i></span>
                <select class="span8" name="consultant"   data-bind="options: $root.doctors,optionsText: function(item){return item.name},optionsValue:function(item){return item.username},selectedOptions: consultant,value:consultant" data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Username :</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i></span>
                <input class="span8" type="text" data-bind="value: username" name="username,valueUpdate: 'keyup'" data-required="true" data-trigger="change" data-remote="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/isUserNameExists" data-remote-method="GET">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Password :</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i></span>
                <input class="span8" type="password" data-bind="value: password" name="password,valueUpdate: 'keyup'" data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Mobile :</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="cus-phone"></i></span>
                <input class="span8"  type="text" data-bind="value: mobile,valueUpdate: 'keyup'" data-type="number" data-minlength="10"data-required="true" data-trigger="change" data-type="phone" name="mobile">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Email address :</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
                <input class="span8" type="text" data-bind="value: email,valueUpdate: 'keyup'" data-required="true" data-trigger="change" data-type="email" name="email">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
     </form>
```

Comment: @downvoter Thanks for downvoting.But please leave a comment too.Please tell me how to improve it

Comment: I cannot follow what is happening in your view model. You are in the `execute` method creating a new vm and call `ko.applyBindings` which rebinds the page and breaks everything. What do you want to achieve in the `execute` method? Also try to please reduce the code and example to a minial level which still includes the complexity but has enough context so your issue can be repdocuded (you should also try to create a fiddle from it).

Comment: Regarding the downvotes: you've posted a bunch of code with only a minimal context and without an actual question just with the statement that it is not working please somebody fix it for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [enabling button when all the fields are filled up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106552/enabling-button-when-all-the-fields-are-filled-up)

Comment: @PatrickSteele cant we ask a question again if the existing question does not solve my problem?

Comment: But you accepted one of the answers as the solution.  So, if it doesn't solve your problem, why did you accept the answer?  Stackoverflow prevents marking a question as a duplicate if the referenced duplicate doesn't have a solution.  Your other question has a solution and this question appears to be the same question.

Comment: @PatrickSteele yes thats true.That question is different and this one is also different and even I have said that i was trying to implement in my project but it did not work.That was question was in general way and this one shows exact requirement

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet. By using file name and file reference you can easily get the idea for how to create folder/file structure for knockout MVVM.

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ViewModels/testViewModel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: EmpNo" />
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: EmpName" />
        <button data-bind="enable: EmpNo() != '' && EmpName() != '' ">
            Submit</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ko.applyBindings(new testViewModel());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**testViewModel.js**

```
var testViewModel = function () {
    this.EmpNo = ko.observable("");
    this.EmpName = ko.observable("");
};
```

Let me know if any concern. If possible then temporary create the new files and check it. so may get idea, how it actually works.

[Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshgoyani/5Dgz3/1/)

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshgoyani/5Dgz3/3/)

Comment: Thanks for answering +1.But I am not getting where to put the codes.I have a very large js files.Do you have gmail so that we can talk there

Comment: Please check the demo. To achieve MVVM please follow the below steps.  1. Please add load Jquery.js file. 2.  Please load Knockout.js file. 3. Please write ViewModel code. 4. next is element/input/button. 5. After that 'ko.applyBindings' code is coming there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code snippet below will only be executed when your asyncCommand executes. So you end up with a form that isn't bound to anything related to your question. To make it work make sure to move the binding setup (ko.applyBindings) outside the execute handler to a location that gets executed when the page is loaded.

```
 var vm = {
                 name: ko.observable(""),
                 password: ko.observable(""),
                    address: ko.observable(""),
                    username: ko.observable("")
                };

                vm.isFormValid = ko.computed(function() {
                    return this.name() && this.password() && this.address() && this.username();
                }, vm);

                ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I have already tried this way.It gives me some different error

Comment: @JqueryLearner Once again. Refactor your problem into a JSFiddle and people will be able to help.

Comment: this is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/rKm9N/2/ but there are lots of code.I have created this fiddle by seeing the other answer also.But I dont know why its not working

Comment: @JqueryLearner That code has so many errors that I don't know where to begin with. You are referencing ko.asyncCommand without defining it. Same with ko.DirtyFlag. You should really start with something simpler until you get the basics of knockout instead of poking around with code snippets taken from everywhere.