# Control button enable in knockout with textInput and with no computed

Tags: knockout.js

The accepted answer here: [SO QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109010/how-to-enable-button-when-input-field-is-not-empty) works with my code like this:

Viewmodel:

```
self.newHealthCategoryName = ko.observable();    
self.isFormValid = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.newHealthCategoryName();
    },self);
```

Html:

```
<input data-bind="value: newHealthCategoryName,valueUpdate: 'keyup'" class="form-control input-inline"/>

{!! Form::submit('Create category',['class' => 'btn btn-primary',
'name' => 'btnhealthcategorycreate','id' => 'btnhealthcategorycreate',
'data-bind' => 'enable: isFormValid']) !!}
```

I tried instead of using these to use textInput in the input element and length of my observable in my button to achieve the same result but i cant. Why?

Failed:

```
{!! Form::submit('Create category',['class' => 'btn btn-primary',
'name' => 'btnhealthcategorycreate','id' => 'btnhealthcategorycreate',
'data-bind' => 'enable: $root.newHealthCategoryName.length>0']) !!}
```

It should work, especially when knockout manual states that:

> Browsers are highly inconsistent in the events that fire in response
>   to unusual text entry mechanisms such as cutting, dragging, or
>   accepting autocomplete suggestions. The value binding, even with extra
>   options such as valueUpdate: afterkeydown to get updates on particular
>   events, does not cover all text entry scenarios on all browsers.
>
> The textInput binding is specifically designed to handle a wide range
>   of browser quirks, to provide consistent and immediate model updates
>   even in response to unusual text entry methods.

Comment: $root.newHealthCategoryName().length > 0

Comment: Can you make fiddle that shows your problem?

Comment: I think i have found the issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the definition of my observable.

It needs to have a default value:

```
self.newHealthCategoryName = ko.observable('');
```